# Robot Framework - How to add thousands commas in a number string

Tags: robotframework

Need help on how to add , in the middle of string

I want to add 2 value.

1. capture the amount. amount show in system exp : 79,000.00
2. remove string , and .00 to convert it to number
3. convert to number
4. evaluate 2 value
5. got the result = ${expectedResults}
6. compare the result with value show in screen.

My issue, the screen show the amount as 80,000.00 but ${expectedResults} display as 80000.00. So robot framework will fail it.

can someone help me how I can add , to make it 80,0000.00

Thank you in advance

```
${list1}=    Get text    xpath=//table[3]/tbody/tr[4]/td[6]
${list2}=    Get Text    xpath=//table[3]/tbody/tr[5]/td[6]
${list3}    Remove String    ${list1}    ,    .00
${list4}    Remove String    ${list2}    ,    .00
log    ${list3}
${list3}    Convert To Number    ${list3}    2
${list4}    Convert To Number    ${list4}    2
log    ${list3}
log    ${list4}
${expectedResults}=    Evaluate    (${list3} + ${list4})
${expectedResults}=    Convert To Number    ${expectedResults}    2
${expectedResults}=    Evaluate    "%.2f" % ${expectedResults}
Log    ${expectedResults}
Table cell Should Contain    xpath=//table[3]    4    6    ${list1}
Table cell Should Contain    xpath=//table[3]    5    6    ${list2}
Table cell Should Contain    xpath=//table[3]    6    10    ${expectedResults}
```

Comment: try [should be equal as numbers](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/2.6.1/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Should%20Be%20Equal%20As%20Numbers)

Comment: Just remove `,` same as in step 2 and assert

Answer (score 1):

To add thousands separator in a number string, use this form of `.format()`:

```
${expectedResults}=    Evaluate    "{:,.2f}".format($expectedResults)
```

`.format()` is much easier and more powerful than printf-style formatting (the construct you're using currently, with the `%`), and if you are running under python version >= 3.6, the f-strings are even better.

The `,` in the formatter is what instructs adding the thousand separator - I don't think it's even an option in the printf formatting, the `.2f` is the precision.

Answer (score 0):

I had solve the issue. using Python> 3.1, use funtion "Format String"

```
${expectedResults}=    Evaluate    (${list3} + ${list4})
${int variable}=    Set Variable    ${expectedResults}
${string var}  =    Format String    {:,}    ${int_variable}
log    ${string var}
```

now it will add thousand separator comma = 80,000.00